# sticky keys in single user mode

Tags: keyboard, console

I have been trying to find a way to enable sticky keys in single user mode but the only thing I can find is in a desktop windowed environment.

Is there a module I need to load or something?

For those that will eventually ask I can only use one hand to type and have occasions where I have to work in single user mode.

Comment: You can get "single handed keyboards" but there is also ["Mirrorboard"](https://blog.xkcd.com/2007/08/14/mirrorboard-a-one-handed-keyboard-layout-for-the-lazy/) which works by re-mapping keys when the Caps Lock is on. Edit: Just noticed Mirrorboard is for a desktop environment :[

Comment: The kernel key translation tables can be set via `loadkeys`, and there's a large number of data files `/use/share/keymaps` for various keyboards and modes, but I'm not sure if there's one with the sticky keys you need. If you have very special wishes, you can also try to write your own mapping files.

Comment: You need to specify _which operating system this is_ in the question.  It's important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-15.html#ss15.1). It says `loadkeys` understands keysyms like `SShift, SCtrl, SAlt` as sticky equivalents you can put in your console keymap.

This [archlinux page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Accessibility) shows you what to do. Basically, create a small keymaps file overriding the keys for shift and so on by the sticky equivalent.  The following might provide you the required set of keycodes:

```
dumpkeys |
awk 'NR==1{print}
     $4~"Shift|Control|Alt"{printf "%s %s %s S%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

Example output:

```
keymaps 0-255
keycode 29 = SControl
keycode 42 = SShift
keycode 54 = SShift
keycode 56 = SAlt
keycode 97 = SControl
keycode 100 = SAlt
keycode 125 = SAlt
keycode 126 = SAlt
```

Put this data in a file `stickyKeys` and load it

```
sudo loadkeys stickyKeys
```

The archlinux page provides you with a suitable systemd unit to load this at boot.  In case of problems you can use `showkey` to show you each keycode as you type the keys.

---

I've not tried this, but when you build the kernel a default keymap is compiled in. You can replace this keymap with your desired one. If we look at the [drivers/tty/vt/Makefile](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/vt/Makefile), we see a rule for `defkeymap.o`

```
$(obj)/defkeymap.o:  $(obj)/defkeymap.c
```

but in the directory there is no `defkeymap.c`. There is however file `defkeymap.c_shipped` and it seems [KBuild](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt#L269) will strip the `_shipped` suffix for the build.
Later in the Makefile there is a comment and optional rule:

```
# Uncomment if you're changing the keymap and have an appropriate
# loadkeys version for the map. By default, we'll use the shipped
# versions.
# GENERATE_KEYMAP := 1
ifdef GENERATE_KEYMAP
$(obj)/defkeymap.c: $(obj)/%.c: $(src)/%.map
        loadkeys --mktable $< > $@
endif
```

So we can see how to create our own `defkeymap.c` file from the current keymap by running

```
dumpkeys | loadkeys --mktable >defkeymap.c
```

Remove the shipped file and try building the kernel. Using `dumpkeys` gives a much larger table than the default, though I don't know why. You may prefer to find the source to your current keymap, say uncompressed`/usr/lib/kbd/keymaps/xkb/gb-intl.map.gz` or similar, edit this with your sticky changes, and then provide this file to `loadkeys --mktable`.

Note that once you have booted, this built-in keymap will probably get overridden early on by whatever mechanism your OS uses to set some standard configured keymap.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! Is this something that can be made into a kernel module to help others when compiling a kernel?

Comment: I added some info on how you might build the keymap into the kernel  binary.

Comment: Thanks again, I will look into this and see if I can get it to work for me.