# how do I enable stickykeys while still in initrd

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, initramfs

Followup to [sticky keys in single user mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342595/3562)

But I don't need it during normal single user. I need it in initrd to enter cryptsetup password. How do I apply a custom keymap to initrd?

The manual gives the declarative form to load a stock keymap: `KEYMAP=y` in `initramfs.conf` but that's too information sparse to be right for custom.

I'm typing one handed due to injury.

how do I enable stickykeys while still in initrd in debian linux?